# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present - Food2Fork API call with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, cors

My group and I are starting our first project, and ten minutes into API testing, I hit a wall and have been unable to create a successful access control header. Can anyone help me work through this error?

```
var userSearch = "chicken"


function apiCall() {

  var queryURL = "http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=3a4f22fb3ddd09f03521f9daf18117a1&q=" + userSearch; //+ "&sort=r"

 $.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
   method: "GET"
 }).done(function(response) {

      console.log(response);

 });
 };

apiCall();
```

"Failed to load http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=3a4f22fb3ddd09f03521f9daf18117a1&q=chicken: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: CORS means you can't access the remote site through a browser directly - proxies are your salvation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774307/7427111

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a reverse proxy to defeat CORS in browser.  You can use a tool like this: [CORS Proxy](http://cors-proxy.htmldriven.com/)